# About the geometric optics approximation in Hawking radiation

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon, geodesics, hawking-radiation

I have read Hawking's famous paper *Particle creation by Black Holes* (Ref. 1) and I have some doubts about the geometric optics approximation and its implications in the argument being made. The derivation has been repeated a number of times in the literature, with some variations; Ref. 2-3-4 are the ones resembling the most Hawking's original argument, to the extent I could find. There was also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/510653/geometrical-optics-approximation-in-general-relativity-expansion-parameter) question, but I don't find the answer and its sources as illuminating as I need.

I will sketch Hawking's argument in the part that is not clear to me. To evaluate the Bogoliubov coefficients $\alpha_{\omega\omega'}$, $\beta_{\omega\omega'}$, we follow *backwards* a solution $p_\omega$ "with zero Cauchy data on the event horizon" i.e. a purely outgoing solution on $\mathcal{I}^+$ (I'll use $\mathcal{I}^\pm$ for null infinity as I don't know other ways to write it). In doing so, we restrict to outgoing waves close to the horizon. Then, by means of *ingoing* null geodesics, we may consider the "affine" distance" between any such outgoing null geodesic and a generator of the event horizon. The affine parameter on these ingoing geodesics is $\lambda \propto U$, where $U$ is a Kruskal null coordinate ($\lambda=U=0$ on the horizon). In other words, for a fixed outgoing null geodesic there is a value $\lambda$ of the affine parameter quantifying the affine distance from the horizon

[image: Fig. 4 from Ref. 1]

Quantitatively, this affine distance may also be expressed in terms of a geodesic deviation, expressed in terms of a vector tangent to the *ingoing* null geodesics $n_\mu$, properly normalized ($n^\mu \ell_\mu=-1$, $\ell_\mu$ being tangent to the horizon null generators).
Such affine distance is constant, since both the horizon generators and an outgoing null geodesics are at fixed $U$, as you can see from the picture above (the fact that we're considering null geodesics should already be an artifact of the geometric optics approximation). Up to this point (which is circled in red in the picture), the reason why affine distance is constant is clear to me. Now the bone in throat: one we arrive at the past end-point of the horizon, we extend back to $\mathcal{I}^{-}$ via *ingoing* null geodesics.
Here the part I'm not sure about: $\ell^{\mu}$ and $n_\mu$ are parallel transported along these ingoing geodesic and for some reason they are flipped, as you can see in the pictures below (taken and edited from Ref. 3): now $\ell$ is tangent to ingoing geodesics.

[image: Ref. 3 pictures]

Eventually, it follows that the affine distance (in the picture $\epsilon$) is constant between the extensions too, actually it's the same up to a factor (for some reason in Ref. 3 is exactly the same, I guess they rescaled the affine parameter). What I mean by this is that this time we measure their deviation by means of outgoing null geodesics. In particular this is done on $\mathcal{I}^-$, where the ingoing Eddington-Finkelstein coordinate $v$ is an affine parameter (because of asymptotic flatness, right?) for null geodesics.

All of this can be summarized by this paragraph on Wald, which remains obscure to me

> However, the behavior of the geodesics sufficiently near to $\mu$ [horizon generator], will be accurately described by a geodesic deviation vector $n^a$, i.e. , the deviation from $\mu$, of neighboring geodesics propagates linearly [why?] along $\mu$,.
> Consequently, choosing the direction of $n^a$ at $\mathcal{I}^-$ to be along the null geodesic
> generator of $\mathcal{I}^-$, we see that near $v = 0$ [as in the previous figure, $v=v_0$ in the first one] the solution will behave as a function of
> advanced time $v$ on $\mathcal{I}^-$ in the same way as it behaves as a function of affine
> parameter a along the geodesic tangent to $n^a$ a at any other point of $\mu$.

I don't really see how these conclusions are drawn, is this just an artifact of the geometric optics approximation? Can't this be proved?

TL;DR: Why is the affine distance preserved on the backwards extended curves?

### References

1. [*Particle creation by Black Holes*](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1103899181), SWH. Pp. 208-209.
2. *General Relativity*, R. M. Wald. University of Chicago Press, 1984. Sec. 14.3, pp. 404-405.
3. [Townsend's review of BH](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9707012). Sec. 7.3, pp. 125-126.
4. [*An introduction to Blach Hole evaporation*](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0010055), Jenny Traschen. Pp. 18-19.